# Can we get random row value from a specific Key inside a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, dictionary-comprehension

I fetched records from a .CSV file into a Pandas dataframe, Then I want to fetch a random record/row in it without using index inside a specific key like French or English. Even a specific row like French word and its English meaning and display the pulled out random record at a specific key/row.

```
#  this is the .CSV file having French word and English meaning

French,English
partie,part
histoire,history
chercher,search
seulement,only
police,police
pensais,thought
aide,help
demande,request
genre,kind
mois,month
frère,brother
laisser,let
car,because
mettre,to put
```

The Python code:

```
data = pandas.read_csv("french_words.csv")

#----converting read .CSV file to dictionary

to_learn = data.to_dict(orient="records")

current_card = random.choice(to_learn)
print(current_card["French"])

#----This is what I want to achieve using dictionary 

#----This is what I tried but can't move forward

words_data_dict = {row.French: row.English for (index, row) in data.iterrows()}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it without using index?

Comment: Andrew Sobolev, I want to do it without index cause I am looking to pull out a random row for both the keys or specified keys using random.choice(). Just like I have done with list specifying French as a Key, there are 2 keys in it French and its corresponding English.  I am a beginner in python so, don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I figured out

```python
# read data from a dataframe into a dictionary
words_data_dict = {row.French: row.English for (index, row) in data.iterrows()}
print(words_data_dict)

# convert the dictionary to a list
list_of_entry = list(words_data_dict.items())
print(list_of_entry)

# generate a random row from the dictionary
random_data = random.choice(list_of_entry)

# specify Key using Index
print(random_data[0])
```